# Struct with pointer fields allocated over void function call

Tags: c, linux, function, pointers, structure

I have a structure like this below and I would like to allocate the members of structA inside the void function as shown below. Basically want to allocate the structure size over the void function using pointer and then use this structure pointer in other functions to access the fields. Below is an example of how I would like to write the code, but not clear of pointer and structure usage. In the print function header, do I use a struct pointer or just the struct itself?

```
typedef struct A {  
    int *x;  
    int *y;  
} A;  

void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A *aType);
void printInfo(A aType);
  
int main() {   
    A genericA;  
    allocateStruct(5, genericA);  
    int x[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};  
    int y[5] = {12, 36, 40, 52, 23};   

    genericA.x = x;  
    genericA.y = y;  
    printInfo(genericA);   
}  

void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A* aType) {  
    aType.x = (int)malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));   
    aType.y = (int)malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));    
}  
 
void printInfo(A genericP) {
    ......  
}
```

Comment: this syntax is wrong. `allocateStruct(5,genericA);` needs to be `allocateStruct(5,&genericA);` and `aType.` needs to be `aType->`. You could pass the object to `printInfo` as you are, but this will make a copy of the structure. If the structure is large (yours isn't), that can be wasted time. Generally, you'll see `const` pointers passed around to functions that shouldn't modify them (like print functions)  so as not to incur the overhead of making a whole new copy of it.

Comment: `allocateStruct(5, genericA);` -> `allocateStruct(5, &genericA);` and `aType.x` -> `aType->x`

Comment: Funny. If I compile your code, fix each error message or warning in the most straightforward way (basically just do what the message propose), it works. I am tempted to close as "not reproducible". What did the messages tell you? Did you read them?

Comment: Thanks @yano - the & solved the compile errors. Can you elaborate on printInfo -  I will change the field values of the struct in later functions and also in printInfo so that the new changes are accessible everywhere in the code. In that case should I send as a copy of the structure or how do I do it.

Comment: Everything in C is pass by value, meaning that when you call a function with arguments, the callee makes _copies_ of the args it receives. Your struct is small (only 2 pointers, probably 16 bytes), but imagine if you had a struct with hundreds of fields. For something that large, you will incur some overhead/time delay simply copying the entire structure. It's more efficient to pass a pointer to the structure. That way, only the pointer is copied (4-8 bytes), and you can access the struct. If it's a function (like a print function) that shouldn't modify the structure, it's prudent to pass a

Comment: `const` pointer, so if you do mistakenly try to modify a field in your struct the compiler will yell at you. But of course, it all depends on what you're trying to do. In some instances you may want a copy of the struct, or a non-`const` pointer to it.

Comment: @yano So, if inside int main() I have A *genericA, how would the function header of void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A *aType) change? and how would it also change for printInfo()

Comment: `allocateStruct` wouldn't change, `printfInfo` would need to accept a pointer argument, `printInfo(A* genericP)` or better yet, `printInfo(const A* genericP)`. Happy to help, but SO questions are not meant to devolve into a running conversation of followup questions strung out in the comments. One specific question for specific answer(s) is the goal. What you're asking about are pretty basic concepts in C, your time will be better spent reading about pointers, memory allocation, and function parameters in a good C book.

Comment: Thanks again @yano This will be the last question on this topic.    `void modifyInfo (A *genericA)`  `genericA->x[0] = genericA->x[0]*2` . If I do this and call `printInfo(A* genericP)` again, I still get 2 instead of 4 for index 0. This could mean my syntax is not correct for modifying the values. Any suggestion would be helpful and this is the last question.  Thanks

Comment: Your math/syntax is fine, if you're not getting the correct result there's a problem elsewhere, which is impossible to diagnose without a [mre]. My crystal ball says a memory allocation/initialization issue. If you can't figure it out ask a new question.

Comment: Solved the last question as : `(genericA->x)[0] = genericA->x[0]*2`   Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I compile your code

```
#include <stdlib.h> 

typedef struct A {  
    int *x;  
    int *y;  
} A;  

void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A *aType);
void printInfo(A aType);
  
int main() {   
    A genericA;  
    allocateStruct(5, genericA);  
    int x[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};  
    int y[5] = {12, 36, 40, 52, 23};   

    genericA.x = x;  
    genericA.y = y;  
    printInfo(genericA);   
}  

void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A* aType) {  
    aType.x = (int)malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));   
    aType.y = (int)malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));    
}  
 
void printInfo(A genericP) {
    /* */  
}
```

I get

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:13:23: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'allocateStruct'
     allocateStruct(5, genericA);
                       ^~~~~~~~
```

So I adapt the call to actually give the pointer the prototype is asking for.

```
#include <stdlib.h> 

typedef struct A {  
    int *x;  
    int *y;  
} A;  

void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A *aType);
void printInfo(A aType);
  
int main() {   
    A genericA;  
    allocateStruct(5, &genericA);  
    int x[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};  
    int y[5] = {12, 36, 40, 52, 23};   

    genericA.x = x;  
    genericA.y = y;  
    printInfo(genericA);   
}  

void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A* aType) {  
    aType.x = (int)malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));   
    aType.y = (int)malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));    
}  
 
void printInfo(A genericP) {
    /* */  
}
```

And I get:

```
main.c: In function 'allocateStruct':
main.c:23:10: error: 'aType' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?
     aType.x = (int)malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));
          ^
```

So I do exactly that:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 

typedef struct A {  
    int *x;  
    int *y;  
} A;  

void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A *aType);
void printInfo(A aType);
  
int main() {   
    A genericA;  
    allocateStruct(5, &genericA);  
    int x[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};  
    int y[5] = {12, 36, 40, 52, 23};   

    genericA.x = x;  
    genericA.y = y;  
    printInfo(genericA);   
}  

void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A* aType) {  
    aType->x = (int)malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));   
    aType->y = (int)malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));    
}  
 
void printInfo(A genericP) {
    /* */  
}
```

And I get:

```
main.c: In function 'allocateStruct':
main.c:23:16: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
     aType->x = (int)malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));
                ^
```

So I do as generally recommended for C and NOT cast malloc:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 

typedef struct A {  
    int *x;  
    int *y;  
} A;  

void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A *aType);
void printInfo(A aType);
  
int main() {   
    A genericA;  
    allocateStruct(5, &genericA);  
    int x[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};  
    int y[5] = {12, 36, 40, 52, 23};   

    genericA.x = x;  
    genericA.y = y;  
    printInfo(genericA);   
}  

void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A* aType) {  
    aType->x = malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));   
    aType->y = malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));    
}  
 
void printInfo(A genericP) {
    /* */  
}
```

Result: No errors, no warnings.

Now test, using the given prototype for the print function and first implementation I can think of:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct A {  
    int *x;  
    int *y;  
} A;  

void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A *aType);
void printInfo(A aType);
  
int main() {   
    A genericA;  
    allocateStruct(5, &genericA);  
    int x[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};  
    int y[5] = {12, 36, 40, 52, 23};   

    genericA.x = x;  
    genericA.y = y;  
    printInfo(genericA);   
}  

void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A* aType) {  
    aType->x = malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));   
    aType->y = malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));    
}  
 
void printInfo(A genericP) {
    printf("%i %i\n",  genericP.x[0], genericP.y[0] );
}
```

And I get the satisfying output:

```
2 12
```

Or the same output with the alternative you mention:

```
void printInfo2(A* genericP) {
    printf("%i %i\n",  genericP->x[0], genericP->y[0] );
}
```

Called as     `printInfo2(&genericA);`.

Admittedly, as yano rightly points out, this is a little too straightforward. It overwrites, from main, the allocated pointers, which represents a memory leak.

I have to guess at the purpose, but I go with yanos assumption that actually  some copying of values (instead of pointers) makes most sense.

As an example for a single value (leaving most of the allocated memory uninitialised, if you do not fill in the `/* more */`), do in `main()`:

```
    genericA.x[0] = x[0];  
    genericA.y[0] = y[0];  
    /* more */
```

Again with the same output.

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch Can I ask additional question? Let's say I have a function updateInfo which will change the x and y values. In this case how will the function header look like and how do I access let's say genereicP.x[0] inside the function. I am new to pointers and structures.

Comment: Yes you can ask an additional question. Use the "Ask Question" button for that.

Comment: Should mention the memory leak, or the proper way to copy `x` and `y` from `main` into `genericA` ... not sure what OP is going for.

Comment: @yano Did and attributed.